# dynamically alter session set WEEK_START in snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to set the week start dynamically like so, but always get the error "invalid value [REPORT_WEEK_START] for parameter 'WEEK_START'".  Any idea on how to do this?

```
create or replace procedure setWeekStart(reportStart date)
returns string
language sql
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$
    declare
        REPORT_WEEK_START number;
        
    begin
        REPORT_WEEK_START := DATE_PART(dayofweek, to_date(:reportStart)); 
        ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = REPORT_WEEK_START;
        
        return 1;
    end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can work around that with an execute immediately

```
create or replace procedure setWeekStart(reportStart date)
returns string
language sql
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$
    begin
        let REPORT_WEEK_START int := DATE_PART(dayofweekiso, :reportStart); 
        execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = ' || REPORT_WEEK_START;
        
        return REPORT_WEEK_START::text;
    end;
$$;
```

First check where we were:

```
SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'WEEK_START' ;
```

| key | value | default | level | description | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WEEK_START | 0 | 0 | SESSION | Defines the first day of the week: 0: legacy Snowflake behavior; 1: Monday .. 7: Sunday. | NUMBER |

and then  use the function:

```
call setWeekStart(CURRENT_DATE);
```

gives:

| SETWEEKSTART |
| --- |
| 2 |

| key | value | default | level | description | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WEEK_START | 2 | 0 | SESSION | Defines the first day of the week: 0: legacy Snowflake behavior; 1: Monday .. 7: Sunday. | NUMBER |

Comment: Very close!  One hiccup: try calling
call setWeekStart(CURRENT_DATE);
twice in a row.  You'll see WEEK_START gets two different values.  It should not change. 

I believe this is because WEEK_START first needs to be set to 1, THEN get the date part, then assign that value to WEEK_START.  But using two execute immediate calls doesn't accomplish this.
Any ideas?

Comment: To get this to work, I need to do something like

create or replace procedure setWeekStart(reportStart date)
returns string
language sql
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$
    declare
        REPORT_WEEK_START number;
        rs date := reportStart;
    begin
        execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = 1';
        execute immediate 'REPORT_WEEK_START := DATE_PART(dayofweek, :reportStart)'; 
        execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = ' || REPORT_WEEK_START;
        
        return REPORT_WEEK_START::text;
    end;
$$;
;

Comment: HAHA, well I just used your logic, which is corrupted by the use of a function `DATE_PART` using `dayofweek` as that uses the current setting of WEEK_START, thus that line should be `dayofweekiso`